# Find id of JSON data in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, associative-array

```
Array([0] => {
    "data": [{
        "id": "91391723276811"
    }],
    "paging": {
        "cursors": {
            "before": "QVFIUmZANLWV5RjJ5SFBWQTE4SV9kbkpIbXFETlVDX19SVnRhaTFhTVFEbTdyYWtjUVRHcV82VUlFaEFpWDZA1WE1ORXE0ZAk5MTWhGV2l6djBMOGwxdzFXYnhn",
            "after": "QVFIUmZANLWV5RjJ5SFBWQTE4SV9kbkpIbXFETlVDX19SVnRhaTFhTVFEbTdyYWtjUVRHcV82VUlFaEFpWDZA1WE1ORXE0ZAk5MTWhGV2l6djBMOGwxdzFXYnhn"
        }
    }
})
```

```
$host = "https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/['form_id']/leads? fields=ad_id & access_token="";
$result = file_get_contents($host);
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
$result = array($result);
print-r($result[0]['data']['id])
```

Comment: ```$id=json_decode($result,true,999,JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR)["data"][0]["id"];```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: print_r($result[0]['data']['id']); your syntax wrong

Comment: This is what you need after the `file_get_contents()`:  $array= json_decode($result,1);  var_export($array);

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to access the id parameter from this data.

```
{
"data": [{
    "id": "91391723276811"
}],
"paging": {
    "cursors": {
        "before": "QVFIUmZANLWV5RjJ5SFBWQTE4SV9kbkpIbXFETlVDX19SVnRhaTFhTVFEbTdyYWtjUVRHcV82VUlFaEFpWDZA1WE1ORXE0ZAk5MTWhGV2l6djBMOGwxdzFXYnhn",
        "after": "QVFIUmZANLWV5RjJ5SFBWQTE4SV9kbkpIbXFETlVDX19SVnRhaTFhTVFEbTdyYWtjUVRHcV82VUlFaEFpWDZA1WE1ORXE0ZAk5MTWhGV2l6djBMOGwxdzFXYnhn"
    }
}
}
```

You can json_decode the data and can access it like `data[0]['id'];`